# adding exception for local files to iecompatdata.xml on Win RT and IE Metro

Tags: windows, flash, tablet, swf

In order to allow flash content, it needs to be added to the iecompatdata.xml file in `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IECompatData\` as part of the under `flash>domain`.

This works fine for websites, but how can I add an exception for local files?

I tired `<domain>C:\</domain>` but that didn't work. Is this possible at all?

Comment: What local files? SWFs?

Comment: yes, local swf.

Comment: because WindowsRT won't let you run non app store software. It fould require an upgrade to Win 8

Comment: Ah, didn't see RT mentioned in the title above. Will check for a working solution, if it exists.

Comment: I decided to give up and return the tablet